# Merge Multiple Pipe Delimited Files Using Awk?

Tags: join, awk, merge

I would like to straight up merge multiple pipe delimited files using Awk. Every example I have found on here is several times more complicated than what i am trying to so. I have several text files formatted identically, and just want to merge them together, like a UNION ALL in SQL. Don't need to join on a column, and don't care about duplicate rows.

Comment: Post some sample data with the expected output and show some work done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(g)awk '{print}' file1 file2 file* >> outputfile
```

Given that you aim to use awk only.
James' answer is way better,
However I still want to show what I came with, the very basic using of awk. :)

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating the files should work for you then:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > finalFile.txt
```

No need for awk.

Answer (score 1):

That is a job for `cat` (see [@mjuarez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53782754/4162356)) but if you really want to use awk for it:

```
$ awk 1 files* > another_file
```